# Any good resources for a non-technical guy to learn software project management?

Tags: project-management

There are many resources on general project management, but are there any specifically for non-technical people for software project management, covering topics such as requirements gathering, use cases and general architecture?

Comment: [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), _almost_ every question tagged [tag:project-management] here and of course [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_project_management).

Comment: I was hoping to get more answers specific for non-programmers who have to lead technical software projects. Usually technical projects involves many technical documents, such as UML, use cases and etc, and literature dealing with those topics are geared towards non-developers, non-technical people.

Comment: That's why I left a comment and not an answer... Answers will come, don't worry :)

Comment: What the non-techie really needs to do is realize what he or she doesn't know.  That's more important than getting a quick introduction to the technical aspects.

Comment: Thanks for lots of good answers. I will track them down at the local library and give the tick to the one which the non-tech guy understands :)

Answer (score 2):

Project Management is a unified issue. Every scenario(that may be the company envo, the team, co-ordinators, clients etc) makes you to adapt around basic fundamentals of sofware development and project management as in whole. There are two books which i would like you to consider and read for implementing better strategies in managing and outputting a project.

1. **[Software Project Management: A Unified Framework](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201309580)** : This book provide detailed study on economics, metrics, and management strategies necessary to plan and execute a software project successfully.
2. **[Software Project Survival Guide (Pro -- Best Practices)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1572316217)** : This one comes from Microsoft publications and in this the Author, Steve McConnell cover the concepts and strategies you need for mastering the development process, including planning, design, management, quality assurance, testing, and archiving

Comment: The first link is to "The No Asshole Rule: Building a Civilized Workplace and Surviving One That Isn't", not "Software Project Management: A Unified Framework"...

Comment: @YannisRizos , extremely sorry for the silly mistake....I have corrected the link

Comment: Though I have to say that the first book (which the link originally pointed to) sounds like a good read too!

Comment: Ya it's a book too....but it deals with more managarial issue rather than the antics of software project development

Answer (score 2):

The two textbooks used in the Software Engineering Process and Project Management course that I took were [Rapid Development: Taming Wild Software Schedules](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556159005) and [Software Project Survival Guide: How to be Sure Your First Important Project Isn't Your Last](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1572316217). Both focus on best practices and techniques for managing software engineering projects. Both books present information from past software projects, in the form of cast-studies.

I'd also highly recommend [Software Estimation: Demystifying the Black Art](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735605351), which focuses on scheduling and estimating software projects. It discusses a number of topics relating to scheduling, estimation, and managing deadlines, along with tools and techniques to best come up with accurate estimates for your projects.

The book used in the software requirements engineering course was [Software Requirements](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735618798). There's also a companion book, with expanded information, called [More About Software Requirements: Thorny Issues and Practical Advice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735622671). These books discuss multiple methods of eliciting, organizing, documenting, verifying, and validating requirements that are appropriate for plan-driven or agile teams.

All of the books I mentioned above are about general project management. Depending on your organization's processes and methods, you might also want to consider resources that discuss those specific processes.

Answer (score 1):

[A Hacker's Guide to Project Management](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750657464) is a good book that will highlight how a lot of developers think in terms of software projects. It is written from the perspective of a guy who loved to code and learned about project management through trial by fire.

It's less formal that a lot of the texts mentioned by others here: It doesn't embrace a single framework. However, I think it will help you learn to recognize where stresses between PMs and coders come from in a lot of cases. Many coders just love to code and find the PM aspect of their work annoying. As with many PM texts, the biggest focus is on how to facilitate and manage communication, including managing expectations.

It's an older book that won't cost you much on Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd read The [Mythical Man Month](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201835959) -- it is a classic in the field of software project management.

As for getting to understand the team, I suggest keeping up on things like [reddit programming](http://reddit.com/r/programming) or [the hacker news](http://news.ycombinator.com/). Much of what is written there will go over your head, but many of the things there are written in English and can give a decent window into the mentality of developers in general.